# ServerSocket.Bind() throws Exception java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

Tags: android

I am new to Android development, I have been searched but no solution work. I also apply a thread in this method but it still not works:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    while(true){
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8990));//this throws exception
            pcSocket=serverSocket.accept();
            reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pcSocket.getInputStream()));
            writer=new PrintWriter(pcSocket.getOutputStream());
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)message+=line;
   
            writer.print(message+"Sent from android");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            pcSocket.close();

            serverSocket.close();
            return START_STICKY;

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception Details

> W/System.err﹕ java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address
> already in use)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.bind(IoBridge.java:89)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer  W/System.err﹕ at
> java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:150)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:282)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer.MessageReply.onStartCommand(MessageReply.java:46)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2868)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
> 04-22 12:41:58.739  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
> 04-22 12:41:58.740  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
> 04-22 12:41:58.740  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 04-22 12:41:58.740  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ Caused
> by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address
> already in use)
> 04-22 12:41:58.740  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> libcore.io.Posix.bind(Native Method)
> 04-22 12:41:58.740  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> libcore.io.ForwardingOs.bind(ForwardingOs.java:40)
> 04-22 12:41:58.740  20055-20055/com.hiddensoft.android.smsannouncer W/System.err﹕ at
> libcore.io.IoBridge.bind(IoBridge.java:87)

The Service is started and stopped by clicking a button

Answer (score 2):

Try to create and bind the server socket outside the while loop.

Comment: Okay but i will then receive the data on time, if not through exception, the will stop the service. i have to run the service running for more data receiving from PC

Comment: Remove the return statement and the socket will still be acepting connections.

Comment: if i remove the return statement then it will produce error as onStartCommand need something to be returned

Comment: So return something after the while loop

Comment: Hay i solved it just by keeping the new serverSocket() statement out of the while loop